# Edit or update the payload in a many-to-many joint table: change or assign a grade on the Contoso University example

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am writing an ASP.Net Core MVC with EF application based on the Contoso University series of tutorials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1

In the [Create a complex data model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1) tutorial (ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core - Data Model - 5 of 10) there is an illustration of the data model implemented.

In the 7th tutorial ([ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core - Update Related Data - 7 of 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1)) Tom Dykstra and Rick Anderson demonstrate how to edit most of the properties in the data model but not how to edit the payload ("Grade") of the "Enrollment" class/table which joins the "Student" and "Course" classes/tables.

**What is the best way to change or assign a grade?
How to you change the "payload" of the Enrollment class?**
I tried adding an EnrollmentsController and associated CRUD views but I get:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY 
constraint "FK_Enrollment_Course_CourseID". The conflict occurred in 
database "ContosoUniversity3", table "dbo.Course", column 'CourseID'.
```

when trying to edit the grade.

I asked this [question](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/7253) on the tutorial itself and Rick Anderson suggested I ask the question here.

Before asking, I searched for the answer and my situation is similar to the one described in [Mapping many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470302/mapping-many-to-many-relationship) or in [Updating in a many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334766/updating-in-a-many-to-many-relationship) but I need an answer using MVC and asp.net core.

[Sql error on update : The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856420/sql-error-on-update-the-update-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-const) helps me understand the problem but not how to solve it in the Contoso University context.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519415/how-to-update-a-collection-in-many-many-by-assigning-a-new-collection

Comment: Your foreign key column value is not present in its reference table column.